# Manage two different versions of Python

Tags: python-3.x, installation

In my system Python 3.8 version already install, but I want create virtual env for version 3.7 on vscode so how can I do>

Answer (score 0):

To work on different environments, you can use Anaconda Prompt.

You can follow the steps given in this: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: can you tell me the another way for this? I want to do it on vscode

Comment: Under the view menu select 'show command pallet'. One of the commands you can then select from the command palette is 'Python: Select Interpreter'. Selecting this option will allow you to choose which version of python to use.